# Building native GCC from sourcecode for ARM

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, nas

My goal: 
installing a working gcc on my Synology NAS DS214+ which has the processor:
Marvell Armada XP Development Board (ARM)
Why? 
Because ipkg (a package installer) does not work 100% with DS214+, therefore if a have a working gcc on the NAS itself I can install new programs by compiling them from source code (making my NAS very flexible to run all programs I want).

My question is where do I start?
I do have an Ubuntu (debian) installation on my 64bit PC, which I can use to build the native gcc. I guess I should be able to cross compile gcc on my Ubuntu OS for the ARM. I can't manage to find a good tutorial.
Any push in the wright direction is appreciated!

Comment: First you need a cross compiler for x86 host and ARM target (build also x86).  Then you need to use this compiler to build an ARM host with ARM target (x86 build).  One way is to use 'crosstool-ng'; first make a ARM cross compiler and then cross compile the ARM native compiler.

Comment: To check I understand you correctly: I need to actually use crosstool-ng to first make a cross-compiler (hence it compiles code for a different target then the host itself). Then I need to use this cross compiler to actually compile the gcc source code to generate the "native ARM compiler"? After that it is just a matter of transfering the native compiler to the target and testing it? Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Comment: you can take the cross compiler route which there are endless numbers of web pages on.  or you can run linux in a virtual machine (qemu) on a virtual arm then do native compiles in that.  there should be many pre-built images for that.  get a raspberry pi and have a native compiler there.  next thing chip....or just go to marvells site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably get this done using [optware-ng](https://github.com/Optware/Optware-ng). Check out the [instructions I wrote for DS215j](https://gist.github.com/ffeldhaus/226f2c5743a7f631806d) which has the same processor type.

When you have installed optware-ng you can just use

```
ipkg install gcc
```

to install gcc 5.3.0 which worked very well on my DS215j.

Comment: This helped me a lot! I finally have the gcc. Do you know for sure that the DS214+ is hard float? Can't really find it back. Still have some problems with compiling a program but I'm not sure if it's due to the gcc version installed.

Comment: According to [this overview on Synology hardware](http://www.synology-wiki.de/index.php/Welchen_Prozessortyp_besitzt_mein_System%3F) (in German) the DS214 has the ARMADA XP (2C/2T) processor which has a VFP unit. I didn't understand hard / soft float completely, but from what I understood it should have hard float.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess it's working fine since it was able to install other stuff. You saved me a lot of headaches!